# Laravel 5 get data other table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have the next stucture: table menus(id, title, type, parent_id, page_id) and
pages(id, alias title,content)
**Model Menu**

```
class Menu extends Model
{

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Menu', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Page', 'page_id');
    }

}

I want get the next result:
-Item 1 (show name menu table)
-Item 2
  -Subitem 1 and alias (show name **menu** table and show alias **page** table)
  -Subitem 2 and alias
-Item 3
  - Suitem 1 and alias
```

Eloquent query

```
$items = Menu::with(['children' => function($query){
            $query->with('page');
        }])->where(['parent_id' => null])->get();
```

view

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @if($item->children()->count() > 0)
            @foreach($item->children as $child)
                <li><a href="/page/">{{$child->title}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
    @else 
      <li><a href="/page/{{$item->page->alias}}">{{$item->title}}
@endforeach
```

How get alias page nested in foreach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
{{ $child->page->alias }}
```

to display child menu page alias assuming you have `page` for each child.

Otherwise you can use:

```
{{ optional($child->page)->alias }}
```

if you are running Laravel 5.5 or:

```
{{ $child->page ? $child->page->alias : '' }}
```

if you are running Laravel < 5.5

Also you could improve eager loading and code a bit:

```
$items = Menu::with('children.page', 'page')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

Comment: I tried, not work. Error: Trying to get property of non-object