# Laravel: Trying to get property of non-Object Error

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables viz:

**Site:**

```
id|name|slug|location|description
```

**Accounthead:**

```
id|accountname|slug
```

**Transaction:**

```
id|name|slug|site_id|accounthead_id|...
```

**My Site model looks like:**

```
class Site extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'location',
        'description'
    ];

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'site_id');
    }
}
```

**My  AccountHead Model Looks like:**

```
class AccountHead extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'slug',
        'accountname'
    ];

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction','accounthead_id');
    }
}
```

**And my Transaction model looks like:**

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function site()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Site','id');
    }
    public function accounthead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AccountHead','id');
    }
}
```

In One of my blade I want to display all the transactions and the associated fields:

**My blade File**

```
@forelse($transactions as $key => $transaction)
<tr>
    <td>{{++$key}}</td>
    <td>{{$transaction->updated_at->format('M d Y')}}</td>
    <td>{{str_limit($transaction->name, 47) }}</td>
    <td>{{str_limit($transaction->accounthead->accountname,47)}}</td>
    <td>{{str_limit($transaction->site->Name,47)}}</td>
    <td>{{str_limit($transaction->amount,47)}}</td>
</tr>
@empty
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-center">No Transactions available.</td>
</tr>
@endforelse
```

It is working fine, unless one **Site**/**AccountHead** is used for more than one **Transaction**. Once a **Site/Accounthead** is used for more than one transaction Its throwing:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Am I missing anything really stupid here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should fix the relationships:

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site', 'site_id', 'id');
}

public function accounthead()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AccountHead', 'accounthead_id' 'id');
}
```

Or just:

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site');
}

public function accounthead()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AccountHead');
}
```

After that, if it still doesn't work, you need to make sure every transaction has both 'site' and 'accounthead' relationships. In other words, every row in the `transactions` table should have a correct ID in `site_id` and `column_id` columns.

If not every transaction has site or account head, you need to check it before trying to use related object property:

```
<td>{{ str_limit(optional($transaction->accounthead)->accountname, 47) }}</td>
<td>{{ str_limit(optional($transaction->site)->Name, 47) }}</td>
```

Comment: I think this is the main issue, If he has `site_id` column for `Transaction` he just leave second and third param,

Comment: After I observed some data in the transaction table, I notice the site_id and accounthead_id with value '0' were causing this error. I am getting these values from the { Form::select}, which gives the index of the site or accounthead in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is typo in your code. Instead of:

```
str_limit($transaction->accountheads->accountname,47)
```

you should have:

```
str_limit($transaction->accounthead->accountname,47)
```

because that's the name of your relationship.

Also it might happen later that you don't have `accounthead` for some relationship - in such case take a look at [Laravel 5 get data other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886122/laravel-5-get-data-other-table/47886146#47886146)

Comment: I am sorry, but that was just the typo in the question. I have edited the question. The error still prevails.